# Creating an enum from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, enums, nsdictionary

Suppose I have an enum as follows:

```
typedef enum {
    FooGoods = 0,
    FooInsurance = 1,
} FooCategory;
```

And I have it as property and ivar in another object

```
@property (nonatomic) FooCategory *category;
```

When I create that other object, I am filling with values from an `NSDictionary` So I do something like this:

```
[baz setCategory:[aDictionary objectForKey:@"Category"]];
```

However because my enum is not a pointer, I get an error.

Doing this get a warning as well, "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion":

```
[baz setCategory:[[aDictionary objectForKey:@"Category"] intValue]];
```

Any other way that is error/warning free?

Comment: what is the baseclass of GIKioskCategory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is not correct

```
@property (nonatomic) FooCategory *category;
```

should be changed to

```
@property (nonatomic) FooCategory category;
```

Now this should work without warnings

```
baz.category = (FooCategory)[aDictionary objectForKey:@"Category"] intValue];
```

Comment: Ahh yes, force of habit. Thanks! Will accept once time limit is past.

Comment: Welcome, it happens to me too :)

Comment: Please dont forget to accept, as i need 8 points before days end  to win a badge :P